# Process stuck after being put into BG

Tags: bash, fedora

I'm trying to put a process into background with (Ctrl+Z + bg):

```
[andrey@localhost dir]$ git clone https://github.com/rust-lang/rust
Cloning into 'rust'...
remote: Counting objects: 465324, done. 
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
^Zceiving objects:  15% (73683/465324), 49.82 MiB | 240.00 KiB/s   
[1]+  Stopped                 git clone https://github.com/rust-lang/rust
[andrey@localhost dir]$ bg
[1]+ git clone https://github.com/rust-lang/rust &
Receiving onjects: 37% (174981/465435), 274.21MB | 217.00 KiB/s
```

Now I'm stuck with the process in the foreground, only now I can't stop it anymore, that is Ctrl+Z doesn't do anything anymore. What have I done wrong?

I'm using bash on Fedora 21 inside a VM.

Comment: There's no evidence there that the process is in the foreground.  [edit] your question and put in the result of the shell's `jobs` command, to start with.  Answerers will also be telling you about terminal modes, so edit in the result of `stty -a` as well to help them.

Comment: From the output the command is in background, it is running and outputting its progress into `stdout`, which is your terminal. What are you trying to achieve?